# Android Push Notification (GCM), is there any Daily Limit?

Tags: android, push-notification, limit, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any daily limit for number push notifications (GCM) can be sent to a particular android application user?

Comment: Do GCM charge anything for the service

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> **Update:** [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) is deprecated, use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

After Google replaced C2DM with GCM, they took off all limits.

SOURCE: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html#history

Prior to GCM (when it was still called C2DM): https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#limitations)

The only limits you run into the GCM documentation is this: <s>http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#lifetime</s>

Quote from the above link:

> Note: There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without
>   collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all
>   stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it
>   receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The
>   application can then handle the situation properly, typically by
>   requesting a full sync.

I am not sure if this is relevant to your question though.

Comment: Noting: `There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded....`, that is just for a specific user, correct? ie. a user may have their device turned off for a long time, thus GCM messages pile up, and if no endpoint, collapse? or is this 100 across ALL users?

Comment: @Sauron: That's per device.

Comment: If don't get this right, the server holds the last 100, older messages are discarded. When the device comes online, the freshest 100 messages are sent along with a limit reached message?

Answer (score 18):

There is a `limit` of `1000` `notifications` at one go.

Assume you have `50000 regids`. You cannot send all `50000` together. After the first `1000`, you will have to separately select the next `1000` and so on.

Answer (score 9):

Doesn't seem there's a set numerical limit, but there are throttling measures in place.

> To prevent abuse (such as sending a flood of messages to a device) and
>   to optimize for the overall network efficiency and battery life of
>   devices, GCM implements throttling of messages using a token bucket
>   scheme.
>
> If an application collapse key exhausts its supply of available
>   tokens, new messages are buffered in a pending queue until new tokens
>   become available at the time of the periodic grant.

Via: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#throttling

**Edit/Update:**

Just to update, the doc for throttling can now be found in the GCM Advanced Topics: http://www.androiddocs.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling

Comment: I just noticed when looking more at the site I added. I'm not entirely sure if androiddocs.com is an official documentation of google. @boltup_im_coding - I'd appreciate if you can add a note saying that. :)

Answer (score 8):

There NOT any daily limit for number push notifications (GCM) but Via Official Source <s>[GCM Advanced Topics](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html)</s> it states that

> There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync.

Hope it will Help.

Comment: can you help me?, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826165/google-cloud-messaging-limit

Comment: @Bhavesh Link not found

Answer (score 4):

Tried to send over 1000 pushes from java code com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender "send" method, attempt fails.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
For Downstream HTTP messages (JSON):

param name - registration_ids 
type - String array

This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.

Use this parameter only for multicast messaging, not for single recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

Comment: First off, welcome to the community :) There are already several high quality answers to this question, most of which were posted three years ago when the question was asked. While it may be a worthwhile exercise to attempt to answer simple questions such as this one in order to further your programming abilities, posting this answer in its current state does not add anything to the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the offical document, NO limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can send Max 1,000 devices per SEND_ID !

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#multicast) is original source.

Comment: That's not what that source says at all.

Comment: ROTFL...the implication of that source is a max of 1000 at one go

Comment: **Source** not found, Change Link.

Comment: How can we increased it then ? @PratikButani

Answer (score 1):

registration_ids
This parameter specifies a list of devices (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Since GCM moved to firebase now, messaging service is totally free.

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/