# Is there limit of android gcm push notification

Tags: android

Is there is any limit of android gcm push notification ?

Actually I am getting message that your GCM subscription expired with device ID: ..............

I have send just 1000 messages only.

Now how to registered the same device again with same sender and application.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15017486/2060383

Answer (score 5):

No there is no limit as @Pals pointed out but there is a [limit on the number of recipients per message](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#multicast). You can send out a message to 1000 users at a time, so if you have more users you'll have to send the message multiple times from your server but to different users each time.

Comment: Is it true that i am not able to receive any message of push Notification as there was more than 1000 Installs by User.

Comment: maybe you can help me, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826165/google-cloud-messaging-limit

Answer (score 0):

Your first question: There is no limits.

Your seconds question:
Unlike IOS, in android the registration_id will expire for certain reason. (e.g. re-install the app)
To be safe, you should update the id to your push server everytime the app starts.