# Access limitation for google cloud messaging

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, limit, google-cloud-platform

What is the access limitation for Google Cloud Messaging? Is this service is totally free of cost? If gcm is paid after a limit then i want to know the pricing. Is anybody can help. I also gone through the google developer console. I got that it is paid after a extent.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108159/is-there-limit-of-android-gcm-push-notification)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Push Notification (GCM), is there any Daily Limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit)