# IBM MobileFirst Broadcast Notification on huge count

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

**Environment Details:**

1. IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1.0
2. Channel: Android & IOS
3. Notifications to be triggered for 15,000 users.

I would like to understand a point how `WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId,notificationOptions)` API works?

Means, I am able to trigger the broadcast notification using the above API and providing the necessary information and received the same in 3 devices.

There is a limitation in GCM that 1000 messages can be sent at a time as per the [limit-of-android-gcm-push-notification.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108159/is-there-limit-of-android-gcm-push-notification)

Does the above mentioned API can handle this scenario? Because more than 1000 there should be another request to be sent as per the above link.

As per [Scalability and hardware Sizing](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/learn-more/scalability-and-hardware-sizing-7-1/?s_tact=C43202QW&s_tact=C43202QW#pushNotifications) a MobileFirst Server can push a notification message to over 22,500 iOS devices, 50,000 Android devices and 350 Windows Phone devices per second.

If my understandings are correct than this API should be able send the 15,ooo notifications without fail by considering the above value as max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of GCM multicast notifications, all Push APIs used by IBM MobileFirst (broadcast or multicast), handle the case of at most 1000 registration tokens at a time. Note that this limit is set by GCM and any GCM client must abide by it.

In case of 15,000 notifications , it will be 15 times 1000 push notifications.

The value of 50,000 Android devices per second, in the Sizing and Scalability calculator, has been derived keeping this limit (1000 messages at a time), in consideration.

Comment: If this the case, API  WL.Server.sendMessage(applicationId,notificationOptions) will taken care of calling the 1000 Push notifications for 15 times with the subscribed push data?

Comment: Yes. From the list of all registration tokens, 1000 at a time * 15.