# is there any daily limit based on the size for Android Push Notification (GCM),

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i went through the article posted here [Android Push Notification (GCM), is there any Daily Limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit)
but what i would like to clarify more is that whether there any limitations would arise based on the size of notifications.. the android app i am developing would include 1000s of notifications so would that make any probs since each notifications carry a size of around 4 kb, if yes wat else i should use.. I was going through REST for instance. TIA

Comment: Why would you need to send 1000s of notifications? Are they 1000 per user or do you just expect that several notifications will be sent to hundreds of users?

Comment: several notifications would be sent and along with that data from table is to be brought as in the changes made in the DB.. SO that would also add to the size right.. in my app many changes would be made daily and table sizes would be big. Would that affect based on the size(use of GCM)?

Comment: Better to send some kind of key, and on the behalf of that key you can pull data from server, every-time you receive a push.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Yes, There is limit for (GCM). That limit is currently 100. for more details see the link here[google push notification(GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)

Comment: would that be based on the notifications or the size of the notifications.? What else to use then?

Comment: it is based on the number of notifications

Comment: it might sem silly.. but even the notification would carry the changes in the DB or it wont?

Comment: The answer is no where related to the question asked.