# Google GCM blocked my server for incomming HTTPS requests

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm a bit confused at the moment. I'm developing an Android application using `Google Cloud Messaging`. I wrote a simple back-end for sending requests to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send everything worked fine the last few days, but suddenly my device stopped receiving messages.

After some hours searching for a solution I tried manually posting a HTTPS POST curl message against the Google Service and received the following error : `We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.`

Ehh? Yep I'm sending automated queries. Thats the whole purpose of the back-end isn't it? Tried the same CURL POST from my home ip-worked like a charm, the phone received the push message. So somehow Google has decided to block requests from my server. Why? It's not a shared server, the IP is static and the GCM back-end is the only thing running on it, making calls against google.com/gcm/send.. In my developer console google has registered a total of 37 calls. So I'm not flooding the server.

Anyone faced something like this? And how should i proceed to resolve it? *(As this is a question regarding a programming "service" I figured it was okay to ask it on SO).*

Answer (score 2):

Link [GCM QUOTA LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit)

There is usage limit for GCM and if you automate the GCM request they consider as a threat as DOS attack

Comment: How to load test then?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not a solution, and I'm not going to mark it as one either. But a temporary fix for me was to edit my hosts file, and point the calls to.

```
173.194.66.95 android.googleapis.com
```

Everything works again, when I point my GCM request to this ip. I dont know for how long, but I'm monitoring my traffic to find the error source. (If any).