# Android Push Notification Limit

Tags: android, push

How many push notifications can we send in Android in a single query and how much time does that query takes to deliver those push notifications

Comment: This is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit

Comment: i already checked this link but its still not clear

Comment: So you need to do google and collect the data.

Comment: great answer dude you are so brilliant

Comment: Stackoverfow it not a place for opinion or statistics, thats why I was refer you to google , you cant find here anything regarding question

Comment: come'on dude is it not obvious that i already googled about it and when i was not able to find anything on google only then i posted a question here. If you'll be able to find a answer on google then please post it here.

Comment: Your question is not matching Stackoverflow standerd thats why I refer you on google,Please read this how to ask a good question, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

as you may read here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#device_throttling

You can send up to 240 messages/minute and 5,000 messages/hour to a single device. This high threshold is meant to allow for short term bursts of traffic, such as when users are interacting rapidly over chat. This limit prevents errors in sending logic from inadvertently draining the battery on a device.

Caution: Do not routinely send messages near this maximum rate. This could waste end users’ resources, and your app may be marked as abusive.

--
deliveries depend on your TTL for messages you set when you are sending. normally if everything is okay it should be delivered instantly.