# How apps get update in their content?

Tags: android

*Apps like* **Facebook,whatsapp,any other news app** *get the things updated * like the status,newsfeed,chats how it works and **is there any tutorial for doing stuff like this(Newsfeed,chat,etc)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular way is to reconnecting to server after specific time. For example use `Handler` to get new updates from server every 30 seconds. Look at below code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        getUpdates();
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
                    }
                }
            }, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

second way to handle this is a push notification from server.

hint: search for "gcm" and have look to this link about its limitations [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit)