# Android GCM message fails to deliver in onMessageReceived.

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM code in m android app which is working fine in many mobile.
but for around 40% apps i am getting success response from google but notification does not arrives in onMessageReceived.

Although little i searched. i found *#*#426#*#* to see google play service logs.
it's showing CANCELLLED.
I don't know why its not coming in onMessageReceived.
[image]

Comment: Might be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit

Comment: Also check if `onDeletedMessages()` is getting called for the special message triggered in case of GCM Throttling

Comment: Have you considered that maximum [4KB limit for data messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#notifications_and_data_messages)?

Comment: my message roughly contains 1K