# Is there any limit on downstream messages from Google GCM?

Tags: android

I receive GCM messages to device. I want to know, is there any limit on Google GCM downstream messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15017586/2183890)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Push Notification (GCM), is there any Daily Limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit)

Answer (score 1):

Google has took away this limit after replacing C2DM with GCM.
There is only limit on stored messages on GCM server. If that limit gets over, then all the messages get discarded.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html#history

Prior to GCM (when it was still called C2DM): https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#limitations)

The only limits you run into the GCM documentation is this: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#lifetime

Comment: Thanks. Very Useful links.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **NO** .

There is no limit. However, there are some throttling measures in place!

> To prevent abuse (such as sending a flood of messages to a device) and to optimize for the overall network efficiency and battery life of
>   devices, GCM implements throttling of messages using a token bucket
>   scheme. 
>   If an application collapse key exhausts its supply of available tokens, new messages are buffered in a pending queue until new tokens
>   become available at the time of the periodic grant.

For more info, refer [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#throttling)