# Performance of google-cloud-messaging

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

We're building an  application server which will be used to send push notifications to android and ios clients via GCM connection server. Our plan is to use HTTP interface to connect with GCM as we only want downstream messaging. could you please tell me what is the performance of GCM for HTTP interface? I'm looking for some kind of performance data like how many push notifications messages per second GCM can support? I checked GCM site but couldn't find this. Please help to guide from where i can get such data?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit

Answer (score 1):

as per the official [Google](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/a9d5NvPz2di) answer

> The rate limit exception code indicates that you are sending messages from a backend server too frequently. To ensure a stable service, there is a per minute / per device app upper limit on the number of messages that can be sent from a backend server. This limit is set high so most well behaving apps should not be affected, all apps should however be prepared to receive this error code.

They do not specify the "actual limit" but they do say `This limit is set high so most well behaving apps should not be affected` so as long as you re not spamming a single device like crazy you should be ok with whatever you send at it.

However please note that you can get throttled and have the messages be delayed

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've also checked some videos of Google I/O 2015 on Cloud Messaging 3.0. In that presentation they said GCM supports 1.1M QPS. and connects with 1.5Billion devices so they're using high end servers and this data is of May 2015. So it would have been scaled further. But this I assume is overall traffic and not specific to HTTP which I was looking. I've checked other related threads and indeed they didn't specified the limit and mostly I found this "This limit is set high so most well behaving apps should not be affected". Guess we need to do perf testing to check.