# What is the daily maximum limit to send GCM messages to android devices?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am searching on stackoverflow & google related to this question but most of the people talking about limit of maximum number of messages sent to a device which is 100.

But my question is bit different,for example, if i have 100,000 users in my app and i need to send push notifications to all then what is the procedure?

**referring to following google api documentation:** https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

**Second parameter:** you can send only 1000 push notifications at once, then how can i send to 100,000 users?  do i need to send 1000, 1000, 1000 etc.. in intervals same day? or maximum 1000 a daily limit?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum number of messages a device can "collapse": 100. This means that if you send 100 messages without the device handling any of them, the 101th will not be received. This can happen if you send a lot of messages while the devices is shut down.

Maximum number of recipients one message can have for one request: 1000. This means that if you want to send a lot of messages, you must do so in batches of 1000

> if i have 100,000 users in my app and i need to send push notifications to all then what is the procedure?

Since there is a limit of 1000 recipients per request, you will have to make 100 requests with the 100,000 registration ids spread over them.

A loop with 100 iterations can do the job, or process your users in batches of 1000.

It is the same for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: That means in same day if i run 100 batches google will not block them am i correct?

Comment: @UMAR yes that should be correct. For google 100,000 is a small number compared to the total, they probably get millions every second