# Firebase Spark Plan Cloud Messaging Limits

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Firebase messaging service in my Application. The only use I make of firebase is to send data from my own created Web services and on the Android App side to receive these messages.

I don't use any other feature at all. I store the device token IDs on my own Database.

Suppose a million users have installed the App. Will there be any disruptions arising? I can't quite make out what the number of simultaneous connections means on the Pricing page. I am using the SPARK Plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *simultaneous connections* referred to in the Pricings Page is for Firebase Realtime Database.

Firebase Cloud Messaging is a Free Service (also see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37962982/4625829)).