# Is there a Firebase cloud messaging throughput limit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any limit for the number of messages that can be sent per second through firebase cloud messaging.

If I want to sent 5000 messages(to 5000 device)  per second. Then is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Pricing and Usage limits for Commercial App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084322/fcm-pricing-and-usage-limits-for-commercial-app)

Comment: Also see these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37961625/4625829, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44798990/4625829

Comment: Have you found an answer? Because the links do not give exact info...