# FCM: What is the maximum number of devices that receiving push message?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is no information of maximum devices that can receiving push notification in Firebase documentation.

If i sending push notification to 1 million device, that is completely free?
I wonder about FCM push notification price policy. Thank you.

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961625/firebase-fcm-usage-limits