# Usage limit for group in fcm

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

We are creating an application where we need to send notification to every user via fcm, we are using group for it. I need to know is there a usage limit to how many users in group we can send notifications to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961625/firebase-fcm-usage-limits

Comment: group limit is not metioned

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of devices/tokens in a [device group is 20](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/device-group). Also note that device groups are no longer present in the latest APIs and will not be further developed.

There is no documented limit on the number of devices/tokens that can be added to a topic.