# how many messages can I send with google cloud messaging per day

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

How many messages can I send using google cloud messaging from my application per day to all registered devices.

Is there any limit per application per day ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the limits are available from Google, and we're not Google. Read the documentation for the cloud messaging and see what (if any) the limits are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Push Notification (GCM), is there any Daily Limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017486/android-push-notification-gcm-is-there-any-daily-limit)